# Is there a way to reload Spring boot application without the need to rerun the application on STS?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using **STS (Spring Tool Suite)** to build a **spring boot** application. Everytime I make some change on my code, I need to stop and run (rerun) the application before I refresh the application page on a browser. It would be very helpful if there is a way that keeps track of the changes I make and include it in the running package whenever I save my changes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `spring-boot-devtools` in your dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Whenever files change in the classpath, applications using spring-boot-devtools will cause the application to restart. The benefit of this feature is the time required to verify the changes made is considerably reduced. More details about springboot devtools is available [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-devtools)